# Output iterated from converting list to dictionary

Tags: python, python-2.7, list, loops

this is an extract (full file has about 8k observations) of my input txt file, containing 3 elements (name, some identifier, year) separated by tab:

```
steve jobs      7653596   2007
john hancock    7653596   2007
```

I tried to put the list in a dictionary using:

```
dictList = []
with open('filename.txt') as fo:
    for line in fo:
        elements = line.rstrip().split('\t')[0:]
        dictList.append(dict(zip(elements[0::3], elements[1::2])))
        print dictList
```

Output after executing the above:

```
{'steve jobs': '7653596'}
{'steve jobs': '7653596', 'john hancock': '7653596'}
```

I'm not sure why the output gives me the result from the first item, and then the second item. I just need the last line generated from the output. Any idea how I should go about doing that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are printing the dictionary on every iteration of the loop instead of after it. Just indent it out, and you should be OK:

```
dictList = []
with open('filename.txt') as fo:
    for line in fo:
        elements = line.rstrip().split('\t')[0:]
        dictList.append(dict(zip(elements[0::3], elements[1::2])))

    print dictList # Here
```